# Python lists and NumPy lists output

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am beginner for python and trying understand difference of array types.

In this example I could not understand that at the end their outputs are different. Why the code behaves differently for the two?

[image: Code Example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy` differs from Python in the way it handles lists (arrays).  `numpy` tries to keep the data buffer intact and not create new copies, while Python will create new objects.  When you do:

```
>>> a = list('1234')
>>> a
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> b = a[1:3]
>>> b[0] = 1
>>> b
[1, '3']
>>> a
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

modifying `b`, did not affect `a`, because `b = a[1:3]` creates a new object.  But in `numpy`, when you do:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> c = np.array(a)
>>> c
array(['1', '2', '3', '4'])
>>> d = c[1:3]
>>> d
array(['2', '3'])
>>> d[0] = 1
>>> c
array(['1', '1', '3', '4'])
```

modifying `d`, *did* change `c`, because `d` is a *view* into the same buffer that `c` is using.

([Source](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html))